# Facebook share button multilanguage

Tags: facebook, share, facebook-opengraph, multilingual

I'm having a problem implementing a requirement that states that I should have a share button with a counter in a multilanguage page and the content of the share dialog should be in the the same language as the page is.

I've read a lot of questions (and suggestions) but I still can´t figure it out.

I've added the meta tags og:locale and og:locale:alternate on my pages and when I use de Facebook debugger I can see two requests on the server logs. The first one without parameters and the second one with the "fb_locale" parameter and the "X-Facebook-Locale" header.

The language is chosen by a url parameter or by a cookie. When the first request comes there is no parameter (or cookie) so the "Raw Open Graph Document Information" comes all in the default language (en_US).

Then, on the second request, (the one with the fb_locale parameter), I set the resources to that language. That sets the "Object Properties" to be in a different language than the "Raw Open Graph Document Information".

The problem is that the share dialog is using "Raw Open Graph Document Information" to populate itself instead of "Object Properties".

I don't understand why this happens and what I can do to use the "Object Properties" instead.

I can't send a parameter with the page language on "data-href" because the share counter will not be the same in both languages.

So far I've managed to have localized resources but with different counter values or have the same counter values only in the defaul language.

Can someone help? Thanks

Comment: Had the same problem with you. Have you solved it?

Comment: Sorry but no. I've used some examples of news, stores and tourism websites with the same behaviour (separate counters for each language) to convince the client thats an acceptable way to implement the functionality. I did not found any website with the same counter for different languages.

Comment: I have a solution if you still need it. check my answer below. it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

When you start creating facebok `share button` on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/
you will see the the modal like below picture...

[image]

as you can see the language_code `(en_GB)` which underlined with red solid line in the picture.

I would want you to pay attention to this language_code in order to make your 
 `share button` multilingual.

You need to replace this `/en_GB/` with `/here-your-language-key-to-change-lang_code/` after you paste the js code into your html page.

I dont know what framework you use. but in my case in Laravel(php framework) it looks like that.

```
src="https://connect.facebook.net/{{@trans('text.lang_code')}}/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v4.0&appId=506295213539017&autoLogAppEvents=1"


en
   'lang_code' => 'en_GB'
es
   'lang_code' => 'es_ES'
fr
   'lang_code' => 'fr_FR'
```

you can check real demo here http://getty.uz

if something is not clear for you please feel free to ask a question in the comment below...

I think this will be helpfull!